# Are there changes in Workbench connecting to Google Cloud MySql?

Tags: database-connection, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I have seen some similar posts, but this one is intriguing me a lot.  I moved from the Pacific area (with my instance in USA Central) to Finland.  I have been able to connect to the MySql database with WorkBench without any issue before (with whitelisted IP address).  Since the move to northern Europe, I have not been able to connect to the DB at all, with no changes to my local setup.
I thought that it may be a time-out issue, but I have just created an instance in the Europe-North region, and the same problem exists.

I have also switched from my company's WiFi (and IP) to a mobile based IP address (I have been able to use both in the past in the Pacific area).

My only remaining (illogical) thought is that is a local firewall issue, but I am not sure and do not know how to fix that.

I am scratching my head - anyone with an answer?

The error messages looks like this (similar to other posts, but with no similar solutions!)

[image]

Comment: New Windows machine in Finland, or same one you've always been on? Is it behind a firewall of some kind on the network now? Or is this your home setup? MOST networks don't limit egress at all, so you can send OUT anything... can you ping the machine IP for the instance (some have it turned off, so this might not work). By default Cloud SQL instances should be ping-able.

Comment: It is the same machine I have been using for the last 4 years (I have used it before in this region with success). This is my home and work setup. I cannot ping my machine (request timed out)

Comment: Okay, sounds like a firewall issue to me probably...Is your Cloud SQL Instance in a VPC? Did you setup firewall rules previously? If you whitelisted your IP before, if you didn't whitelist the new IP that wont work, but I'm assuming you did that already (double check your public ip with whatsmyip.org). If it's local, double check Windows Defender and see if it's doing bad things.

Comment: Make sure that you whitelist your current IP address by configuring access to your Cloud SQL instance [1]. I would recommend you to connect using the client in the Cloud Shell to disregard a problem with your CloudSQL instance. Here [2] you can find how to connect to your instance. This connection would be between the cloud shell VM and your instance. This might help you troubleshoot firewall misconfigurations from your side.

[1] <https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#configure-instance-mysql>
[2] <https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#cloud-shell>

Comment: I have whitelisted my IP all the way (I work out of office most of the time, and therefore sometimes use a mobile hotspot, so I am very familiar with that process).  I have an unused machine, will try from there and see what happens.  It also seems that I will have to learn how to use the Google Cloud Shell as an alternative!

Comment: Cloud Shell is indeed a good alternative. Also using Cloud SQL Proxy could help you with your problem. Please let me know if you've had any progress with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have moved locations, you likely have changed IP addresses as well. Make sure that you have authorized your network's current IP, and that your firewall is open to your instances public IP on port 3306.

You can also look into using the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy), which doesn't require authorizing an IP address.